# What is the best way to use an external drive with a double USB plug on a laptop with only USB-C ports?

Tags: usb, optical-drive, external-drive

I have an external optical drive that has a double USB connector, presumably to supply more power to the drive. I have a 2019 16" Macbook Pro with only USB-C plugs.

Is there any risk of harming the drive or computer by plugging the drive into two USB-C ports using two adapter dongles? Is there a better way to use this drive with a computer with only USB-C ports?

[Y-connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWV27.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a double adapter dongle.

Y-Cables were from the USB 2.0 time, when each port supported only much lower power requirements from the device - the Dongle just harnessed the power output of two sockets. Since USB 3.0 this is no longer a serious limit for an optical drive.

Just plug the "first" (Data and Power) end of the Y-Cable into your USB-C via an adapter and ignore the "second" (Power only) end.

Comment: FYI: *The cable that comes off the main cable is considered the "second" cable*